# R optim, can I pass a list to parameter :par?

Tags: r

**Question:**

I am using `optim` to optimise my function. However, my function have 2 paramters, first is a scalar, second is a dynamic length vector.

I initialized parameters with a list and then pass into `optim` function. Raise the following error, it seems `par` in `optim` can only get a vactor input? Since my second parameter has dynamic length, it's difficult to use a vector of parameters and then slice with `y <- para_vector[slice]` to pass them to `y`.

For instance:

```
# I dont know the length of second elements
para <- c(1,3,2, ... ,283)
x <- para[1]
# I can't slice the vector and pass value to y
y <- para[2:?]
```

**Code:**

```
obj <- function(para){
  ### input:
  ### para is a list with 2 elements.first element is scalar, second element is vector 

  # x is a scalar, stored in the first position of para list
  x <- para[[1]]
  # y is a vector with unfixed length, so I store it in the second element in a list
  y <- para[[2]] 

  value <- x^2 + sum(y^2)
  return(value)
}

para_initial = list(1,c(0,1))

optim(par = list(1,c(0,1)),fn = obj)
```

**Output:**

> Error in optim(par = list(1, c(0, 1)), fn = obj) : 
>     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: No you can't do what you want. The function passed to `optim` may only take a fixed length vector.

Comment: @Bhas When we fix `para_initial`, the length  of function's parameter is the same with `para_initial`, so `optim` can perform on it. I think there must be a way to solve this problem, otherwise why `lm` works well with dynamic dataframes?

Comment: Can't you simply say `par = unlist(para_initial)` ?

Comment: I failed with vector parameter, since the length of second elements is dynamic. Can you give an code example, if you can do this? @HansW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your objective function because, as Bhas said, optimization solvers require parameters as vectors. If it is difficult to change the `obj()` function, you can write a wrapper for it that splits the input vector into a list.

```
obj_wrap <- function(x) {
    obj(list(x[1], x[2:length(x)]))  ## CORRECTED
}
```

Now sove it by applying `optim` to this function.

```
para_initial = list(1,c(0,1))

optim(unlist(para_initial), fn = obj_wrap)
## $par
[1]  4.575264e-05  1.710995e-05 -5.172657e-05
## ...
```

which looks a bit clumsy, but would be possible and gives a correct result..

Comment: Shouldn't `x[2,length(x)]` just be `x[-1]`?

Comment: Or `x[2:length(x)]`?